# CSS3 transition fadein with display:none

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've got some element I want to **fade** with **CSS3**. It can be simply done by 2 classes with `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1`, but problem is faded element is some dropdown menu and it has **elements under** it, so even if it has opacity: 0, its still **'clickable'** and elements **under** it are not.

If I add `display: none;` attribute, element is **not animated.**

Is it possible with **css only** to avoid it?

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property) but didnt find working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Eh7jr/

Comment: Could you please provide a demo?

Comment: If you want to disable it then you might probably want to use jquery as well. If so you can easily write the style for hover as well as disable the dropdown also.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh7jr/

Comment: @RoyMJ I think purpose of CSS3 transitions is to dont use jQuery for this kind of animations. I know I could simply .fadeIn() but I want to stick to css3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `display:none`, try using `visibility: hidden;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tHnbM/)**

See [this article](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/) which states:

> visibility animates despite the CSS Basic Box Model spec saying
>   “Animatable: no”

Comment: visibility still blocks.

Comment: works nice for tooltips in combination with @Ben's answer `pointer-events:none;` that prevents hover and click events on the target

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by 100% CSS pure code.

```
.menu > li > ul{
    display: none;
}
.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeInFromNoneIE;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    1% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNoneIE {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    1% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    1% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `display: none` when element is not `:hover` will make **fadeOut** instant (no animation at all). Still I couldn't find better solution till today.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an element not accept clicks with this:

```
.hidden
{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Browser support is excellent, except of course for IE. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: well then I cant accept it, site is unusable when you will go to dropdown menu position clicking on 'register' inside header covered by dropdown opacity: 0.

Comment: So then the logical answer to your question is that it is *not* possible with CSS only, if you are needing IE support. You'll want to use JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed the example in the JS Fiddle above was broken, fixed the code here:

```
 <style>
div {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 2s;
}
div.opa {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class=opa>dsdsds</div>
<br> <br>
<p><a href="#">clickme</a></p>
<script>
$('a').click(function(){
    $('div').toggleClass('opa');    
})
</script>
```

Fixed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHnbM/9/):

Answer (score 0):

try to make an element that do not accept click by applying z-index to negative value.

```
a{z-index: -999;}
```

Oh! I understood your problem. You can set `visibility: collapse;` better than hidden I think.